# Getting the integer index of a Pandas DataFrame row fulfilling a condition?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
   a  b  c
b
2  1  2  3
5  4  5  6
```

As you can see, column `b` is used as an index. I want to get the ordinal number of the row fulfilling `('b' == 5)`, which in this case would be `1`.

The column being tested can be either an index column (as with `b` in this case) or a regular column, e.g. I may want to find the index of the row fulfilling `('c' == 6)`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You could use [np.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where) like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,7).reshape(2,3),
                  columns = list('abc'), 
                  index=pd.Series([2,5], name='b'))
print(df)
#    a  b  c
# b         
# 2  1  2  3
# 5  4  5  6
print(np.where(df.index==5)[0])
# [1]
print(np.where(df['c']==6)[0])
# [1]
```

The value returned is an array since there could be more than one row with a particular index or value in a column.

Comment: Instead of doing `np.where(df.index == 5)[0]`, pandas has a `get_loc` function which seems more kosher. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html

Comment: @hlin117 - your comment should be the correct answer, please add it

Comment: Looks way tidier and more comprehensible than the pandas approach.

Answer (score 75):

Use [Index.get_loc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) instead.

Reusing @unutbu's set up code, you'll achieve the same results.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np


>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,7).reshape(2,3),
                  columns = list('abc'),
                  index=pd.Series([2,5], name='b'))
>>> df
   a  b  c
b
2  1  2  3
5  4  5  6
>>> df.index.get_loc(5)
1
```

Comment: This is not what OP wants. You are answering the question, "What is the ordinal location of a given index?". OP wants to know, "What is the ordinal location of a row that fulfills a given condition?". That is, the input is a certain condition e.g. (df.b == 5) or (df.c == 6).

Comment: OP said "The column being tested can be either an index column (as with b in this case) or a regular column, e.g. I may want to find the index of the row fulfilling ('c' == 6)"

Comment: Note that Index.get_loc() only returns an integer if the index has all unique values.  Otherwise, it returns a boolean mask array.

Comment: I added an alternate answer that always returns an array of integer values as the return type, whether searching based on index or a column, and whether or not the index has unique or non-unique values.

Answer (score 15):

With [Index.get_loc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) and general condition:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np


>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,7).reshape(2,3),
                  columns = list('abc'),
                  index=pd.Series([2,5], name='b'))
>>> df
   a  b  c
b
2  1  2  3
5  4  5  6
>>> df.index.get_loc(df.index[df['b'] == 5][0])
1
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers based on Index.get_loc() do not provide a consistent result, because this function will return in integer if the index consists of all unique values, but it will return a boolean mask array if the index does not consist of unique values.  A more consistent approach to return a list of integer values every time would be the following, with this example shown for an index with non-unique values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {"A":1, "B":2}, {"A":2, "B":2}, 
    {"A":3, "B":4}, {"A":1, "B":3}
], index=[1,2,3,1])
```

If searching based on index value:

```
[i for i,v in enumerate(df.index == 1) if v]
[0, 3]
```

If searching based on a column value:

```
[i for i,v in enumerate(df["B"] == 2) if v]
[0, 1]
```