# How to select range of rows until a specific row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, slice

I have a Pandas dataframe. I have selected a row from that dataframe.

I now need to select a range from that dataframe where the row is and going back 55 rows, if there is so many.

Here is some pseudo code, hope it helps:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(...)
row = df[3454]

index = row.index
start = max(0, index - 55)
end = max(1, index)
dfRange = df[start:end]
```

Comment: does your code not work? You are better off using `iloc` syntax as what you are doing only works if those index values exist

Comment: Also if you haven't already read the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)

Answer (score 23):

This should do it

```
integer_location = np.where(df.index == 3454)[0][0]
start = max(0, integer_location - 55)
end = max(1, integer_location)
dfRange = df.iloc[start:end]
```

This link has more info
[Getting the integer index of a Pandas DataFrame row fulfilling a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199288/getting-the-integer-index-of-a-pandas-dataframe-row-fulfilling-a-condition)

Comment: But `iloc` doesn't actually operate on the dataframe `index` — it operates on row indices, which might not be the same — and even if you have an integer `index`, once you start slicing your dataframe, it might not be contiguous or start with 0.  I guess if I want a range of rows between two `index` values, I could try to figure out the row indices first and then apply this method?  Something like...  `df_reindexed = df.reset_index(); start = df_reindexed[df_reindexed['index'] == start].index[0]; end = <similar>; df_reindexed.iloc[start:end]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can slice a dataframe, so to select a range until a certain point, one could slice. The simplest case is to slice `df` until the specific index and call `tail()` to get the specific range of rows. For example, to get the 55 consecutive rows until a particular index, you could use the following:

```py
slice_length = 55
particular_index = 3454
df.loc[:particular_index].tail(slice_length)
```

For a more elaborate method that uses a single boolean indexing, one could use a combination of `cummax()` and `cumsum()` and slice using `between()`.

```py
df.loc[df.index.to_series().eq(particular_index)[::-1].cummax().cumsum().between(1, slice_length)]

# if `df` is MultiIndex
df.loc[df.index.to_frame().eq(particular_index).all(axis=1)[::-1].cummax().cumsum().between(1, slice_length)]
```

A working example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(6), 'B': range(6,0,-1)}, index=[f'a{i}' for i in range(6)])

slice_length = 3
particular_index = df.iloc[4].name
df1 = df.loc[:particular_index].tail(slice_length)
```

[image: res]